# Errors when trying to use ValueListenableBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying update a list with the changes in current but `ValueListenableBuilder` is giving errors

```dart
         ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: currentColor,
              builder:  (BuildContext context, String current, Widget child) {
                child: PaginateFirestore(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                  itemBuilder: (index, context, documentSnapshot) {
                    final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map?;
                    return MainComponent(
                        title: data == null ? 'Error' : data['id']);
                  },
                  // orderBy is compulsory to enable pagination
                  query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('transfer')
                      .orderBy('id', descending: decen),
                  // to fetch real-time data
                  isLive: true,
                );
              }),
```

Error:

```
    The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.

    The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, String, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, String, Widget?)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `builder` parameter is a `function` that returns a `Widget` and not a `Widget`, so you cant use `child` here.

Update the builder function and add `return` in the place where `child` is used.

The second error is a type mismatch, update the builder line and add a `?` after widget, the line should read.

`builder:  (BuildContext context, String current, Widget? child)`

Comment: Can you please look at this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235146/update-list-by-new-orderby-string-flutter-firestore-list